# try and catch does not catch promise errors

Tags: node.js

Following is my code

```
try {
    const connect_to_database = async () =>{
        const sequelize = new Sequelize('testing','sugumar','mypassward',{
            host:'127.0.0.1',
            dialect:'mysql'
        })
        await sequelize.authenticate()
    }
    connect_to_database()
} catch(e) {

}
```

I don't want to throw any errors, but it throws error in the terminal

part of the error is

```
(node:25701) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'sugumar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/home/user/Desktop/sugumar/testing/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:125:19)
at tryCatcher (/home/user/Desktop/sugumar/testing/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/user/Desktop/sugumar/testing/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@JonasJancarik/handling-those-unhandled-promise-rejections-when-using-javascript-async-await-and-ifee-5bac52a0b29f

Answer (score 1):

You have to await the promise function call like this `await connect_to_database()`.

`connect_to_database` function is `async` which means it returns a `promise`.

Comment: Thank you for effort, even it is a promise, we can use await only inside the async call. await should return then result or throw the error, in this case it should throw the error, which I want to catch in catch block.

Comment: I believe you can't. You have to use `.catch` (`connect_to_database().catch(error => console.log(error))`) for it since you are not calling the function from async scope.

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan You're not understanding how promises work. The error occurs asynchronously, and you can only use `try-catch` with promises by (1) putting them in an async function and (2) awaiting them. If you can't do that, or don't want to, then your other option is to use `.catch()` or `.then(null, error => { /* handle error */})`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code , see if it works as I am currently working on Sequelize only.

```
const sequelize=new Sequelize('database','root','password',{host:'localhost',dialect:'mysql',logging:false});
sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) 
{
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(function(err)
{

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I can follow the document, but want to know why my code is not working.

Comment: Why don`t you just resolve the error which it is showing? Just asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const connect_to_database = async () => {
  try {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('testing', 'sugumar', 'mypassward', {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      dialect: 'mysql'
    })
    await sequelize.authenticate();
  } catch (error) {

  }
}

connect_to_database();
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have put try catch only for the await call